# Non-public API usage ItunesConnect warning

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode7, pspdfkit

After updating PSPDFKit library in my application. But the interface of the library didn't change much from the previous version. Then  I had uploaded it for internal testing(I use Xcode 7.0.1.) and received next warning:

[image: iTunes Connect: Your app "********" (Apple ID: ********) has one or more issues]

I can see the build on iTunes page but it already almost 24 hours in Processing state.

The questions are:

1)If anyone received the same recently?

2)If there connection between the warning and Processing state taking so long?

3)Is this warning really can lead to rejecting the application?

And I saw similar questions on Stack-overflow but they seem to be outdated.

Answer (score 0):

if an app use non public api then app will be rejected from apple.
This written on apple page
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the PSPDFKit SDK authors.

None of the mentioned method names are private API and we haven't seen such a report so far. Please contact us at support.pspdfkit.com directly so we can work out what's going on here. Since we recently released PSPDFKit v5, many companies updated their apps so we can say with guarantee that our product does not get flagged on iTunes for such issues.

I also recommend updating Xcode, as we only list Xcode 7.1 and higher as compatible: https://pspdfkit.com/changelog/ios.

Comment: Update: This has been successfully resolved a few days after they contacted us.